# How to take text from a text field to a JLable in another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a UI for a football simulator using Java and have been stuck on a problem on some time. I am trying to transfer a user inputted team to another JLabel on another JFrame.

I have already tried getters and setters but I don't know where when to call them.

First frame (where jtextfield is):

```
String userinput1 = Home.getText();
System.out.println(userinput1);
String userinput2 = Away.getText();
```

Second frame (where jlabel Home is):

```
JLabel Home = new JLabel("");
Home.setBounds(333, 33, 46, 14);
frame.getContentPane().add(Home);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

When I print `userinput1` in the second frame, I expect to see the name of the football team entered, e.g. "Arsenal", but the actual output is null.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want(IMO) is to have a static class, where the data that you want to share is.

For example, lets say that I have two JFrames, in one JFrame I ask someone for their phone number, but in the second JFrame I want to display that phone number. I would have something similar to this:

```
public class UserData{
    private static String _phoneNumber = "";
    private static ArrayList<Runnable> listeners = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

    public static void listenForUpdate(Runnable run){
        listeners.add(run);
    }

    private static void update(){
        for(Runnable r: listeners){
            r.run();
        }
    }

    public static void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        update();
    }

    public static String getPhoneNumber(){
        return _phoneNumber;
    }
}

public class InputFrame extends JFrame{
    // ... other code here
    ... onInput(String phoneNumber){
        UserData.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
}


public class DisplayFrame extends JFrame{
    public DisplayFrame(){
        super();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("default");
        add(label);
        UserData.listenForUpdate(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                label.setText(UserData.getPhoneNumber());
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```